# Bash boolean expression and its value assignment

Tags: bash

Is there a way to to evaluate a boolean expression and assign its value to a variable?

In most of the scripting languages there is way to evaluates e.g

```
//PHS
$found= $count > 0 ;  //evaluates to a boolean values
```

I want similar way to evaluate in bash:

```
BOOL=[ "$PROCEED" -ne  "y" ] ;
```

This is not working and tried other way but could not get a boolean value. IS there a way to 
   do this WITHOUT using IF ?

Comment: The shell doesn't really have booleans. Maybe you should instead use `true` and `false`, which are trivial commands which simply set their exit code (the implementation is basically `exit 0` and `exit 1`, respectively). Then you can do stuff like `bool=false; $bool && echo "Yes"; $bool || echo "No"; while $bool; do sleep 1; done` etc.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You could do:

```
[ "$PROCEED" = "y" ] ; BOOL=$?
```

If you're working with `set -e`, you can use instead:

```
[ "$PROCEED" = "y" ] && BOOL=0 || BOOL=1
```

<sub>`BOOL` set to zero when there is a match, to act like typical Unix return codes. Looks a bit weird.</sub>

This will not throw errors, and you're sure `$BOOL` will be either 0 or 1 afterwards, whatever it contained before.

Comment: `-ne` and co. are "**arithmetic** binary operators" (`man bash`), and should not be used for strings. Just use `=`.

Comment: This method is not compatible with `set -e`, which many recommend for [writing robust shell scripts](http://www.davidpashley.com/articles/writing-robust-shell-scripts.html).  I made another suggestion in my answer.

Answer (score 22):

I would suggest:

```
[ "$PROCEED" = "y" ] || BOOL=1
```

This has the advantage over checking `$?` that it works even when `set -e` is on.  (See [writing robust shell scripts](http://www.davidpashley.com/articles/writing-robust-shell-scripts.html).)

Answer (score 16):

Rather than using `... && BOOL=0 || BOOL=1` suggested in the currently-accepted answer, it's clearer to use `true` and `false`.

And since this question is about bash specifically (not POSIX shell), it's also better to use `[[` instead of `[` (see e.g. [1](https://google.github.io/styleguide/shell.xml#Test,_%5B_and_%5B%5B) and [2](https://www.oilshell.org/blog/2016/10/12.html)), which allows using `==` instead of `=`.

So if you had to use a one-liner for something like this in bash, the following would be better:

`[[ "$PROCEED" == "y" ]] && should_proceed=true || should_proceed=false`

Then you can use the derived variable ergonomically in boolean contexts...

```sh
if $should_proceed; then
  echo "Proceeding..."
fi
```

...including with the `!` operator:

```sh
if ! $should_proceed; then
  echo "Bye for now."
  exit 0
fi
```

Answer (score 8):

Assignment:

```
found=$((count > 0))
```

For a boolean test:

```
BOOL=$(test "$PROCEED" = y && echo true || echo false)
```

In general, a

```
x=$(...)
```

assigns the output of ... to the variable x. The `y` does not need quotes, because it contains nothing which needs to be masked.

A `-ne` is used for arithmetic comparison; see `help test` for an overview and quick reminder.

Comment: Works for arithmetic tests only.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the accepted answer, the return value seems odd as `true` will return `0` and false `1`. To make it easier to understand:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
test=$( [[ $1 == "y" ]]; echo $(($? == 0)) )
echo "$test"
# It will print "1", otherwise "0".

# To use it in conditions:
if [ $test ]; then 
...
fi
```

Another way is:

```sh
test=$( [[ $1 == "y" ]] && echo "true" || echo "false" )

# In this case `[]` are not required:
if $test; then
  ...
fi
```